# Google Sheets Sending Email Twice

Tags: javascript, loops, email, google-apps-script, conditional-statements

I have created a google apps script to automate emails based on a certain condition. It works, but has a major bug that I can't figure out.

The bug is that it will send out two emails at the same time, the first email is correct and contains all the information that I need, the second will contain the same headings but no values.

I just want to know why it sends the second email.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var spreadSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
if(spreadSheetName === "KOSU"){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("KOSU");

 var localTime = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
 var actualKosu = ss.getRange("B30:T30").getValues()[0];
 var predictedKosu = ss.getRange("B25:T25").getValues()[0];
 var hourlyProduced = ss.getRange("B29:T29").getValues()[0];

 var timeRange = ss.getRange("B19:T19").getValues()[0];

//loop through range of times and compare values
//grab actual kosu, predicted kosu, hourly produced then email to relevant people

for(var i = 0; i < timeRange.length; i++){
  if(localTime >= timeRange[i] && localTime < timeRange[i + 1]){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: 'person@gmail.com',
            subject: "KOSU UPDATE",
          htmlBody: 
           '<div>' +
           '<h3>SWI1 - KOSU UPDATE</h3>' +
           '</div>' +
          '<div>' +
          '<h3>PREDICTED KOSU:'+ Math.round(predictedKosu[i]) + '</h3>' +
          '<h3>ACHIEVED KOSU:'+ Math.round(actualKosu[i]) + '</h3>' +
          '<h3>HOURLY OUTPUT:'+ Math.round(hourlyProduced[i]) + '</h3>' +
          '</div>'
        });
       }
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: It would help if you provide an example of the sheet that you have. Did you try anything so troubleshoot this? Add some logging in your for loop to understand what values are being processed. If an email is sent too often, you either have too many values in your `timeRange` value or your if statement is not strict enough. Check what sort of values are passing through. If you can give examples of what data is being passed through that shouldn't be there, it's a lot easier to determine where the issue is.

Comment: Do you have multiple triggers installed? Why are you using both the reserved function name `onEdit` (which created a simple trigger), and an installed edit trigger (because you need that authorization to send emails)

Comment: In your for loop you compare the values at [i] and [i+1] but what if [i+1] and [i+2] also meet the criteria that would cause 2 emails and perhaps more if [i+2]/[i+3] etc. also meet the criteria.  Try putting a break after MailApp.sendEmail so only the first comparison match triggers an email.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions and help.

It turns out that I managed to link it to a backup version of the sheet, so it was sending out information from a blank sheet and the intended sheet.